# Stock Item Attribute on Inventory Lookup filter error

Tags: acumatica

I have Attributes on a Stock Item and added those attributes to the Inventory Lookup screen on Sales Orders.

This works ok. But when creating a filter I get this error:

The multi-part identifier "InventoryItem.NoteID" could not be bound.

Error:

[image]

Here is my code for adding the attributes:

```
public class SOSiteStatusSelectedExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOSiteStatusSelected>
 {
    public abstract class itemAttributes : IBqlField { }
    [PXAddAtttributeColumns(new[] { "Attribute1", "Attribute2", "Attribute3" },
            typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID),
            typeof(InventoryItem.noteID))]
    public virtual string[] ItemAttributes { get; set; }
}


public class PXAddAtttributeColumns : CRAttributesFieldAttribute
{
    string[] _names;

    public PXAddAtttributeColumns(string[] names, Type classID, Type noteID)
       : base(classID, noteID)
    {
        _names = names;
    }

    public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
        this._IsActive = true;
        base.CacheAttached(sender);
    }

    protected override void AttributeFieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e, PXFieldState state, string attributeName, int idx)
    {
        if (_names.Any(attributeName.Equals))
        {
            state.DisplayName = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state.DisplayName)) ? (state.DisplayName.Replace("$Attributes$-", "")) : attributeName;
            state.Visible = true;
            state.Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Dynamic;
        }

        base.AttributeFieldSelecting(sender, e, state, attributeName, idx);
    }
}
```

The attributes defined on the stock item is being displayed correctly on the grid, but as soon as I do a filter, I get the error.

Also when creating a saved filter like this, I get the error.

Filter Settings:

[image]

Not sure what is causing this?

In response to the first comment below, I created a fresh instance of Acumatica with some demo data. Used an attribute called COLOR and added that attribute as a column on the Add Stock Item screen from Sales Order Entry.

Here is my project XML.

```
<Customization level="" description="" product-version="20.112">
    <Page path="~/pages/so/so301000.aspx" pageSource="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">
        <PXGrid ID="gripSiteStatus" ParentId="phG_PanelAddSiteStatus_gripSiteStatus" TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGrid">
            <Prop Key="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="AppendDynamic" />
        </PXGrid>
    </Page>
    <Graph ClassName="SOSiteStatusSelected" Source="#CDATA" IsNew="True" FileType="NewFile">
        <CDATA name="Source"><![CDATA[using ARRegisterAlias = PX.Objects.AR.Standalone.ARRegisterAlias;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;
using Message = PX.CarrierService.Message;
using POLine = PX.Objects.PO.POLine;
using POOrder = PX.Objects.PO.POOrder;
using PX.CarrierService;
using PX.Common;
using PX.CS.Contracts.Interfaces;
using PX.Data.DependencyInjection;
using PX.Data;
using PX.LicensePolicy;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing.Common;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing.Helpers;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing.Interfaces;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing;
using PX.Objects.AR.MigrationMode;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CA;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.Common.Bql;
using PX.Objects.Common.Discount;
using PX.Objects.Common.Extensions;
using PX.Objects.Common;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.DR;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.PaymentTransaction;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.IN.Overrides.INDocumentRelease;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.SO.Attributes;
using PX.Objects.SO.GraphExtensions.CarrierRates;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.TaxProvider;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOSiteStatusSelectedExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOSiteStatusSelected>
  {
        public abstract class itemAttributes : IBqlField { }
        [PXAddAtttributeColumns(new[] { "COLOR" },
                typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID),
                typeof(InventoryItem.noteID))]
        public virtual string[] ItemAttributes { get; set; }
  }
          
     public class PXAddAtttributeColumns : CRAttributesFieldAttribute
    {
        string[] _names;

        public PXAddAtttributeColumns(string[] names, Type classID, Type noteID)
           : base(classID, noteID)
        {
            _names = names;
        }

        public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
        {
            this._IsActive = true;
            base.CacheAttached(sender);
        }

        protected override void AttributeFieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e, PXFieldState state, string attributeName, int idx)
        {
            if (_names.Any(attributeName.Equals))
            {
                state.DisplayName = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state.DisplayName)) ? (state.DisplayName.Replace("$Attributes$-", "")) : attributeName;
                state.Visible = true;
                state.Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Dynamic;
            }

            base.AttributeFieldSelecting(sender, e, state, attributeName, idx);
        }
    }        
          
          
}]]></CDATA>
    </Graph>
</Customization>
```

The works in adding the column to the table, but when I create a filter on that column and save it as a filter, I get the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe you need more context here. When you say "I...added those attributes to the Inventory Lookup screen on Sales Orders." What exactly did you do? Can you provide your project.xml? I ask because I took the code as is and the error doesn't occur, indicating the other changes you made may be partly responsible.